# Forming Watertight mesh

Tags: meshlab

Am new to mesh formation and using meshlab application. Am currently facing an issue in creating watertight mesh in meshlab. It would be helpful if anyone address this issue.

[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2x5atZNkPWdIW2i23PL2SKENvSVmh7m/view?usp=sharing)

I have uploaded my .obj mesh file in this google drive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Comment: I have tried forming mesh from .pcd data in cloud compare application. Since meshlab doesnt support .PCD data. The method used to form mesh is Delaunay 2.5D (X-Y) plane fit. The mesh formed from this has some holes and gaps. Tried to close the mesh in meshlab application. But except for the convex hull method to form the closed object none of the other mesh correction algorithm doesnt helps. My ultimate aim is to calculate volume from the mesh formed from point cloud data. So in order to do that i need to form a closed object.

Answer (score 1):

The surface mesh in your file is too noisy to be useful for any measure. I have reconstructed a much better surface from the same point data using the filter "Surface reconstruction: Ball Pivoting", where you can clearly see the 3 flat layers of the data.

[image]

If your purpose is to measure the volume of the data, I would just take measure of the data (size of each layer and distances between layers) and then compute the volume as the sum of the two truncated pyramids.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Will it be possible to create mesh from Surface reconstructed data in mesh lab.

Comment: Yes, the Ball Pivoting method will create a mesh like a show in the right image. That mesh will have small holes that ypu can close with the filter "Close Holes"

Comment: I want to create a closed mesh. So that i can calculate volume from "compute geometry measures'. Currently am getting an error for mesh volume parameter saying the mesh was not water tight.

Comment: If you want the volume of that set of points, the best you can do is "compute convex hull"+"decimation"+"compute geometric measures"

Comment: How to determine the parameters to be passed for decimation process in mesh lab.

Comment: Decimation is quite optative here, and just used as a way to "denoise" the values obtained for the volume. The decimation will remove small triangles that add (or substract) very small values of volume. Just apply "Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation" to reduce the number of triangles to a value between 1/2 and 1/10 of the original number of faces in the convex hull.